# Store: Can I create shipping zones?

Tags: expresso-store, shipping

In shipping methods, is it possible to setup zones? For example rather that setting up a separate method for ever country in Europe, can I create a single shipping method for Europe and add in the European countries?

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to do using the CP. However, it's possible to write a simple shipping plugin, and group your shipping rules for various countries.

For example, you could put this into a file named `store/libraries/store_shipping/store_shipping_example.php`:

```
class Store_shipping_example extends Store_shipping_driver
{
    /**
     * Calculate the shipping total for an order.
     * Use print_r($order) to see all the fields available to you.
     * The fields available also match those in the Checkout tag:
     * http://exp-resso.com/docs/store/tags/checkout.html
     *
     * @param array $order
     */
    public function calculate_shipping($order)
    {
        $eu_countries = array('uk', 'ie', 'fr', 'de', 'es', 'it');

        if (in_array($order['shipping_country'], $eu_countries))
        {
            return 15.00;
        }
        else
        {
            return 30.00;
        }
    }
}
```